# AsyncTask download zip file android

Tags: android

when i try to download .zip file. I don't get complete file, size of file is 3.93 MB but i get only 38KB.Don't get complete .zip file
Here is my Code

1. Activity Class

   ```
    private Button btnStart;
           // Progress Dialog Object
           private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
           // Progress Dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
           public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
           // Music resource URL
           private static String file_url = "http://www.mediafire.com/download/tvd070dounxk472/al_Quran_ul_Hakeem.zip";
   @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.main);
               btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
               btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       btnStart.setEnabled(false);
                       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/al_Quran_ul_Hakeem.zip");
                       // Check if the Music file already exists
                       if (file.exists()) {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File already exist under SD card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   ```

   }

   else {

   ```
   new DownloadMusicfromInternet().execute(file_url);
   }
   ```

   }
      });
    }
2. AsyncTask Class

   class DownloadMusicfromInternet extends AsyncTask {

   ```
           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();
               // Shows Progress Bar Dialog and then call doInBackground method
               showDialog(progress_bar_type);
           }

           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
               int count;
               try {
                   URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                   URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                   conection.connect();

                   int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                   // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                   InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),100*1024);
                   // Output stream to write file in SD card
                   OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/al_Quran_ul_Hakeem.zip");
                   byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                   long total = 0;
                   while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                       total += count;
                       // Publish the progress which triggers onProgressUpdate method
                       publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                       // Write data to file
                       output.write(data, 0, count);
                   }
                   // Flush output
                   output.flush();
                   // Close streams
                   output.close();
                   input.close();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
               }
               return null;
           }

           // While Downloading Music File
           protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
               // Set progress percentage
               prgDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
           }

           // Once Music File is downloaded
           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

               dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: what value you are getting from `conection.getContentLength()` ?

Comment: i m getting lenght of my file to update progress bar

Comment: It seems alright, maybe the link is the issue. By the way, don't forget to close the streams on the finally block, the current approach is a bad practice.

Comment: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you checked you can really download that file? If I open that link I am redirected to a webpage, not the download itself.

So check what you are getting is not really the HTML page... If this is the case, you will need a direct download link.

**EDIT**: BTW the direct download link of that file is `http://download2010.mediafire.com/ugkwnc164pqg/tvd070dounxk472/al_Quran_ul_Hakeem.zip`, but I don't know if this is a fixed link or changes from time to time...

Comment: link is changing from time to time ..how can i get fixed link and direct to download file not to html page

Comment: because the link which i was using ...directly downloading file but not it is opening html page

Comment: So using the direct link works? Regarding if being fixed or not, if you want that the link to be constant you could ask MediaFire if they provide such functionality, use a different service that could give you that (ex: DropBox with public folder links) or you would need to get the HTML page first, and then parse it to find the direct link in there... Of course the first/second options would be a lot easier.

Comment: @user3582794 If this solved your problem please marked it as solved.